# Android phone does not recognize that there is a backup in Google Drive

Tags: restore, lg, 8.0-oreo, google-backup

I have backed up my phone (LG G7 ThinQ) to google drive and I am trying to restore my app data. The problem is that when I go into the settings app under the backup and restore option, it tells me that there is no backup in the drive. I am running android 8.0 oreo and I was also running it when I made the backup.

I know for sure that I am signed into the account with the backup. I've tried resetting the phone and removing and re-adding the account but it still says that my drive does not have a backup.

What is causing this and how do i fix it?